# What is meant by credit-based investment?

Tags: macroeconomics

My knowledge of economics is very small so I would be grateful if anyone could answer this question in the style of 'economics for dummies'!

What is meant by the term 'credit-based investment' or 'credit-fuelled investment'? I have come across the term a number of times describing China's fiscal policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name suggests, credit based investment is investment that takes place based on funds that are themselves borrowed.

An example of credit-based investment is leverage.